# Rails : recognized route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to get hold of the route recognized by rails given a path?

Current implementation of rails in the methods "recognize_path" && "recognize" returns just the hash with the :controller, :action and :id (if available) and any other url attributes. But I would like to get the route object (wihtin the ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes) that rails compares the path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about why you want to do this? There's might be a different solution to your problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And, what weppos said.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response, I was out of town. As far as why I want to get hold of the route object rather than just the controller and action for the current request is that I want to generate navigation using routes. If I know the current object, I could extend the RouteSet and Route classes by adding some methods such as ancestors, parent, child, childrent for the Route and get the navigation elements like breadcrumbs, tabs,... If its not clear let me know, I will try to provide some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relevant parts of #recognize_path to get at the Route object:

```
req = @request_class.new(env)
@router.recognize(req) { |route, matches, params| ... }
```

This will give you a [Journey::Route](http://rubydoc.info/gems/journey/1.0.4/frames) object.

It's worth considering if this is the best way to do this, if all you want to do is generate breadcrumbs. I'm not sure you'll be able to inspect the route object for enough information to generate breadcrumbs automatically.